# Is there any way to force the viewport to orbit the geometry center of the selections not the origin point

Tags: 3d-view

when you toggle "orbit around selection" the fact is that the viewport orbits the origin point of your selection. and that origin point is not always at the selection's geometry center, sometimes even at the world origin, which makes the viewport navigation so frustrating.
Is there any way to force the viewport around the selection's geometry center no matter where its origin point is.

Comment: Preferences -> Navigation tab -> Orbit & Pan panel -> Orbit Around Selection orbits around the selected object based on geometry, not the origin point, so I am not sure what you are talking about. Could you clarify? Numpad . also centers the selection based on geometry not the origin. Maybe you have some floating vertices somewhere far away or your geometry is affected by something?..

Comment: I forgot to mentioned it is in edit mode
https://www.udrop.com/KSDP/2023-09-28_23-57-42_rf22.00.mp4

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I haven't noticed this before.. in Edit Mode the orbit seems to be about the mean vertex location, (weighted towards density)?  Where it would make more sense to orbit around the selection's bounding box center?

Comment: I don't know what would make more sense. For me personally, the default Blender's navigation settings work absolutely fine without all this stuff. I was also going to suggest locking the view to 3D Cursor like Harry McKenzie answered.

Answer (score 2):

My frustrations with viewport navigation have ended once I started using *Lock To 3D Cursor*. I just simply <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to set the 3D Cursor to my point of interest and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd> to pan drag the view until the 3D Cursor is in the center of my viewport and my viewport navigation works perfectly. Or in your case set it manually to the geometry center. This also has always solved my zooming far in problems. I'm just confused why so many people don't use this feature. I have never found any reason to disable this so it's permanently enabled for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: kind of solved my problem but still, just not as smooth as I expected, thanks anyway